# How to automatically create one pattern for each imported midi track?

Tags: midi, fl-studio, importing

I'm using FL Studio 12. When I import a MIDI file with multiple tracks, it creates a single pattern (and a separate channel for each MIDI track). I can then click on "Split by channel" to split the pattern (see screenshot).

But then I still have to cycle through all the patterns and place them in the playlist.

I would like to get every MIDI track as a separate pattern placed in its own playlist track. I'm planning on generating a MIDI file with dozens of tracks and would like to be able to turn the various tracks on/off with 1 click after the import.

Any ideas on how I could achieve that?

[image]

Comment: While this is an subjective view, I've found FL studio very lacking - since everything involving midi took me a lot more time to do than using other daws.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking in the Pattern's name at Playlist window title is showed the **Pattern clip sources** selection list, this is the nearest way to do what you would like.
By this selection list is easy and fast to select another pattern to Draw/Paint it to each desired Playlist track.
[image: Pattern clip sources selection list]

A function like *each Patern to a Playlist track* which you would like to get of the Playlist window there will never be because isn't the proposal of the Playlist window use, the channels into patterns in the FLStudio are like module's samplers allocators.
Imagine you have a tape with a several session recordings parts as a database of the good recording clips - so is how are the Patterns in FLStudio, and the Channels are these recordings clips which can be *Patterns Clips* ([virtual] instruments, layers, [MIDI Out] controllers and samplers), *Audio Clips* (recordings and samplers) and *Automation Clips* (closely related to Event automation).

> The **Playlist window** is a stack of **multi-purpose 'Clip Tracks'** that can host *Patterns Clips*, *Audio Clips* and *Automation Clips*. Unlike most other sequencers, the Playlist tracks are not bound to any one instrument, audio recording or even Clip type. **You can put any Clip type anywhere and even overlay Clips.** Think of Clips as a little like notes in the Piano roll. When the play-head reaches a Clip, FL Studio plays whatever the Clip instructs it to do.

*Source: https://www.image-line.com/support/FLHelp/html/basics_workflow.htm#Workflow_arranging*